# Use of __declspec() in GCC or G++ (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, arm

What is the use of __declspec() in GCC compilers? From some research i found that it is a Microsoft specific extension to access shared .dll libraries. So what is it's use in Linux(or Rots like mqx)? This is a piece of sample code that i found which is to be compiled with GCC.

```
__declspec(section "configROM")
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen gcc being used on Windows ... And I'm pretty sure this is not available for other targets than Windows. So where did you see that on Linux software?

Comment: Are you compiling for linux target or microcontroller target ? if it's for microcontroller target, the fact you are on windows or on linux doesn't matter, `__declspec` acts always on same way

Comment: yeah. It's for a micro controller. The OS is not exactly Linux it's more like an Rtos( MQX to be precise).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would imagine that an **ARM** running some obscure **WindowsX/ARM** system would also need your `__declspec`; conversely, your `__declspec` has no sense on Linux/x86.

AFAIK,

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

And there is no equivalent of `__declspec(dllimport)` in linux to my knowledge.

#### dllimport/dllexport

> On cygwin, mingw and arm-pe targets, __declspec(dllimport) is
> recognized as a synonym for __attribute__ ((dllimport)) for
> compatibility with other Microsoft Windows compilers.

Have a look at this visibility support from GCC, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: My system is running MQX RTOS which is not at all based on any Windows OS. It was used to get config file from ROM.