# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token with __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++

I've looked through a few posts on this same error and it seems this happens when the compiler can't find a constructor that matches the signature?

But I can't rule out the possibility since my case is rather different - it has a `__declspec(dllexport)` and I'm not sure if this it the culprit causing the problem.

Here is the error message:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA/Vignetting_corrector/C++/Vig_Correction/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target correction
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correction.dir/Vig_Correction.cpp.o
In file included from /media/yuqiong/DATA/Vignetting_corrector/C++/Vig_Correction/Vig_Correction.cpp:5:0:
/media/yuqiong/DATA/Vignetting_corrector/C++/Vig_Correction/ColorCorrection.hpp:16:10: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 _declspec(dllexport) int VignettingCorrectionUsingRG(unsigned char* pImage, int ht, int wd,
          ^
/media/yuqiong/DATA/Vignetting_corrector/C++/Vig_Correction/Vig_Correction.cpp: In function ‘int VignettingCorrect(IplImage*)’:
/media/yuqiong/DATA/Vignetting_corrector/C++/Vig_Correction/Vig_Correction.cpp:47:65: error: ‘VignettingCorrectionUsingRG’ was not declared in this scope
  int flag=VignettingCorrectionUsingRG(pImageBuffer, sht, swd, vp);
                                                                 ^
CMakeFiles/correction.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/correction.dir/Vig_Correction.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correction.dir/Vig_Correction.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/correction.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/correction.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my `ColorCorrection.hpp` file...

```
#ifndef COLOR_CORRECTION_HPP
#define COLOR_CORRECTION_HPP

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

__declspec(dllexport) int VignettingCorrectionUsingRG(unsigned char* pImage, int ht, int wd, vector<double>& vp);

#endif
```

Thanks so much for your help in advance...

Comment: Try deleting `__declspec(dllexport)` and see what difference it makes.

Comment: `__declspec` is an MSVC compiler extension and it looks like you're using GCC.

Comment: @john Now it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Quentin right I suspect that's the reason too but am not fully sure if `__declspec` works under Linux. Seems I don't need that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610241/use-of-declspec-in-gcc-or-g-linux

Comment: ***not fully sure if __declspec works under Linux*** Since there is no MSVC linux compiler (that I know of) I would say it does not work under linux.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the clarification!

Comment: So we have all the answers in the comments section (which worked) and nothing in the answer section. Now what?